# Discrete categories / isomorphic objects in ncatlab

Tags: category-theory

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/discrete+category

Section 2, Categorical meaning, says that for discrete categories an object only connects to itself by it's identity morphism. Why doesnt the map $x \rightarrow x+1$ for the integers connect the objects? Is the section only talking about inclusion maps to open sets?

Comment: The category associated to the ordered set $\mathbb{N}$ is not discrete.

Comment: The discrete topology on $\mathbb{N}$ does not imply that $\mathbb{N}$ has to be a discrete category ?

Comment: @reputationgrinding Just because two mathematical concepts have the same word in their name doesn't mean they have anything to do with one another. Your question is like assuming $H$ is a [normal subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup) of $G$ and concluding that [every two disjoint closed sets of $H$ have disjoint open neighborhoods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add to the current answer that you seem to be confusing 3 different things, which each are a category associated to $\mathbb{N}$:

- the discrete category associated to $\mathbb{N}$: for any set $X$, you can take a category whose objects are the elements of $X$, and the only morphisms are the identity of each object;
- the category associated to $\mathbb{N}$ as an ordered set: for any (partially) ordered set $(X,\leqslant)$, you can define a category whose objects are the elements of $X$, and there is a unique morphism $x\to y$ iff $x\leqslant y$;
- the category associated to $\mathbb{N}$ as a topological space: for any topological space $X$, you can define the category associated (like in the previous point) to the ordered set $\mathcal{O}(X)$ of open subsets of $X$, with the inclusion. That is, the objects of this category are the open subsets of $X$, and there is a morphism $U\to V$ iff $U\subset V$.

When applied to $\mathbb{N}$, this gives three different categories, although the first one is a subcategory of the second one (they have the same objects, but the second one has more morphisms), which can also be seen as a subcategory of the third one by sending $n\mapsto \{0,\dots,n\}$.

Note that since $\mathbb{N}$ is a discrete topological space for its canonical topology, the objects of the third category above actually are all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. On the other hand, it is not at all a discrete category.

Fun fact: $\mathbb{N}$ can also be called a discrete ordered set. This does not imply that any of the second or third categories above is discrete, but it does imply that $\mathbb{N}$ is discrete as a topological space. Words are funny.

Answer (score 0):

The category you are looking at, is probably the category on $\Bbb N$ generated by the natural order $\le$, and as you observed, it's simply not a discrete category, as we have an arrow e.g. $1\to 2$ which is not the identity of any object.

For any set (class) one can define a discrete category, just by introducing identity arrows for each element. 
We can do this to $\Bbb N$ as well, but then we won't have any arrows between different numbers.